# how to soup get certain script div in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a web where the response  is

```
<script>
var 1 
var 2
</script>
some data

<script>
var pagename:{somedata};
var pagelist:{"totalData":549,"totalPage":12,"pageSize":48,"currentPage":1};
</script>
```

I've tried using

```
products_per_page =soup.find_all('script')
for x in products_per_page:
   print(x.text)
```

This doesn't work at all.
I am trying to get the totalPage in var pageList that's located in a script.
Please help

Comment: _doesn't work at all_ is useless problem description. Check [ask]. Post [mre],  incl. full traceabck if you get any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html_string, "html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all("script")

for script in scripts:
    if "pagelist" in script.text:
        print(script.text)
```